# Call original method on a @Spy then throw an exception

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have a `@Transactional` method that I must test when the transaction fails after it is called, for example :

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Transactional
    public void myMethod() {
        // [...] some code I must run in my test, and throw an exception after it has been called but before the transaction is commited in order for the transaction to be rolled back
    }
}
```

Here is the test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @SpyBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        doAnswer(/* some code which would call the real method, then throw an exception in order to cancel the transaction */)
        .when(myService).myMethod();
        // [...] other code that test other services when that service failed in the transaction but after its real method has been correctly executed
    }
}
```

Could you tell me what code to put in the `/* ... */` part in my test?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `invocation.callRealMethod()` then `throw` some exception inside the `doAnswer`:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        invocation.callRealMethod();
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    })
    .when(myService).myMethod();
    // [...] other code that test other services when that service failed in the transaction but after its real method has been correctly executed
}
```